# android layout id naming: use of R.group instead of R.id

Tags: android, layout, naming-conventions, android-resources

I've seen that all the layout ids are identified by @+id/viewid, but it seems the @+my_group_name/viewid works as well. Is it normal to use this naming convention, or the id must be in the "id" class ? I've checked the forum and found prefix based naming conventions but nothing like this.

In examples: I have a dialog layout called dlgeffect. In this layout:

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+dlgeffect/text"
    android:layout_width="0dip" ... >
```

I now the id's are reused, but during layout modifications if the ids are unique for the whole project the compiler gives error this way (and not runtime error)

Thanks,
Gzp

EDIT: and of course from java it is referenced as R.dlgeffect.text

Answer (score 0):

I really dont know if you can do this, but always stick to standards, if you want it for reuse porpuse or setting property for more than element at once you can use same id for different element